# Thread Safe Events while utilizing EAP

Tags: c#, asynchronous, event-handling

This is my code for a server using EAP (Sockets).

Is `AsyncOperation.Post` the right way to raise thread safe events?

`AsyncOperation.Post` states:

> Invokes a delegate on the thread or context appropriate for the application model.

Is there any other mistake in the code (i.e something that can be improved or is a bad thing to do)?

```
public sealed class Server
{
    private Socket _server;
    private SocketAsyncEventArgs _acceptArg;
    private AsyncOperation _asyncOperation;

    public EndPoint LocalEndPoing { get; private set; }
    public bool Listening { get; private set; }

    public delegate void ErrorOccuredEventHandler(Server sender, Exception e);

    public delegate void ClientConnectedEventHandler(Server sender, EndPoint remoteEndpoint);

    public event ErrorOccuredEventHandler ErrorOcurred;

    public event ClientConnectedEventHandler ClientConnected;

    private void OnErrorOccured(Exception e)
    {
        if(ErrorOcurred!=null)
            ErrorOcurred.Invoke(this,e);
    }

    private void OnClientConnected(EndPoint remoteEndPoint)
    {
        if(ClientConnected!=null)
            ClientConnected.Invoke(this,remoteEndPoint);
    }

    public Server(EndPoint localEndPoint)
    {
        LocalEndPoing = localEndPoint;
        Listening = false;
        _asyncOperation = AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(null);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Listening)
                return;

            _server = _server ?? new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            _server.Bind(LocalEndPoing);
            _server.Listen(10);

            Listening = true;

            _acceptArg = _acceptArg ?? new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            _acceptArg.Completed += _acceptArg_Completed;

            if (!_server.AcceptAsync(_acceptArg))
                _acceptArg_Completed(null, _acceptArg);

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _asyncOperation.Post(ex=>OnErrorOccured(ex as Exception),exception);
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        try
        {
            if(!Listening)
                return;

            _server.Close();
            _acceptArg.Dispose();

            _server = null;
            _acceptArg = null;

            Listening = false;

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _asyncOperation.Post(ex => OnErrorOccured(ex as Exception), exception);
        }
    }

    private void _acceptArg_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
        {
            _asyncOperation.Post(remoteEndPoint=>OnClientConnected(remoteEndPoint as EndPoint),e.AcceptSocket.RemoteEndPoint);

            //Do nasty things with the accepted socket

            e.AcceptSocket = null;

            if(!_server.AcceptAsync(e))
                _acceptArg_Completed(null,e);
        }
        else
        {
            _asyncOperation.Post(ex => OnErrorOccured(ex as Exception), new SocketException((int)e.SocketError));
            Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> public EndPoint LocalEndPoing { get; private set; }
> ```

should be `LocalEndPoint`.

---

> ```
> public void Start()
> {
>     try
>     {
>         if (Listening)
>             return;
> ```

why is this `if` statement inside the `try..catch` ? It can be granted that this won't ever throw any exception. As a rule of thumb, only put code inside a `try..catch` which can throw.

You should always use braces `{}`, although they might be optional, to make your code less error prone.

> ```
> _server.Listen(10);
> ```

why `10` and not `1000`? Using magic numbers should be avoided to make the code easier to read and understand. You should extract magic numbers/strings into meaningful variables/constants so **Sam the maintainer** will see at first glance what this is about.

---

> ```
> _asyncOperation.Post(ex=>OnErrorOccured(ex as Exception),exception);
> ```

Let your variables and operators have some space to breathe, its just making your code more readable like so

```
_asyncOperation.Post(ex => OnErrorOccured(ex as Exception), exception);
```

---

> ```
> private void _acceptArg_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
> ```

having an underscore prefixed methodname is a **no go**. Underscore prefixing is tolerated for class level variable names only.

Comment: Thanks for the advises....really appreciate it. But the actual question is whether `AsyncOperation.Post` is the right way to raise the events...?

Comment: As long as the application is not a console application it should be. Take a look at [`Notes to Inheritors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asyncoperation.post%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_2)

Comment: what if I'm developing a class library?